# Jest "No tests found" after update VSCode to 1.32.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I'm using debugging jest with vscode config, here is `launch.json` configurations:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Jest Current File",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
            "args": [
                "${relativeFile}"
            ],
            "env": {
                "cross-env": "1",
                "NODE_PATH": "./src",
                "__PLATFORM__": " WEB",
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "windows": {
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This configurations worked properly until I updated VSCode to 1.32.1. Now when I run Jest current file, the console prints out like this:

```
Debugger attached.
No tests found
In D:\workspace\my-project
  747 files checked.
  testMatch:  - 747 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 747 matches
  testRegex: (\\__tests__\\.*|(\.|\\)(test))\.js?$ - 15 matches
Pattern: src\utils\storage\my-file-name.test.js - 0 matches
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After install old version VSCode (1.30.2), I saw the output:

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       9 passed, 9 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.866s
Ran all test suites matching /src\\utils\\storage\\my-file-name.test.js/i.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Difference is `Pattern`:

- v1.30.2: `/src\\utils\\storage\\my-file-name.test.js/i.`
- v1.32.1: `src\utils\storage\my-file-name.test.js`

VSCode change their `${relativeFile}`'s seperator from `\\` to `\`, this is why `jest` couldn't find out test file

---

For those who are being stuck, just change `"${relativeFile}"` to `"${fileBasenameNoExtension}"` in `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Jest Current File",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
            "args": [
                "./${fileBasename}"
            ],
            "env": {
                "cross-env": "1",
                "NODE_PATH": "./src",
                "__PLATFORM__": " WEB",
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "windows": {
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For anyone else who has multiple test files with the same name, this answer may not work, as jest will run all test files with the same name. Instead, you can replace `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` with `${file}"`. 
You should also include the `--runInBand` argument if you don't want Visual Studio Code to open a new terminal every time you run your tests: `"args": ["${file}", "--runInBand"],`

Answer (score 1):

Better use `--runTestsByPath ${relativeFile}`, which always works.

Comment: I have several tests with the same name in different directories, and adding the `--runTestsByPath` flag for windows worked for me!: `"args": ["test", "--runInBand", "--no-cache", "--no-watch", "${relativeFile}"], "windows": {"args": ["test", "--runInBand", "--no-cache", "--no-watch", "--runTestsByPath", "${relativeFile}"]},`